# How do I store private user images in a filesystem and not hamper their privacy?

Tags: php, mysql, filesystems, cdn

I have a project that deals with storing sensitive private images or other files from the user. I have done a bit of study about storing files like images in file system or databases.

I have come up with the decision to store them in a CDN like facebook does. But how do I ensure someone doesn't break through someone else's privacy just by tinkering with the URL and replacing random characters?

For example: Suppose I have two images in my CDN file system,

Uploaded by user1-
https://somecdnlink.com/somelocation/1234abc-5678pqr.jpg

Uploaded by user2-
https://somecdnlink.com/somelocation/1234abc-5679pqr.jpg

Now user2 after uploading their pic decided to check the image url. The image they just uploaded popped out exposing the location where it is stored.
 Then he decides to check what happens if he decrements the number 9 and writes 8 in that place.

This would automatically open up user1's image which he stored in the cdn server and is supposed to be private.

How do I ensure that user2 doesn't have access to the other user's images in the file system? How do facebook like giants do that?

The images could be very big and about millions of such images may exist.

I could try randomising the file names and maybe do hashing and stuff, but a bruteforce like attack trying out every possible permutation could easily expose a lot of pics.

Also, is storing in a database a better option in such a case rather than a cdn?

I am using php and mysql.

Comment: Authentication! Check that the user is the owner of the resource before outputting. Obscurity is not suitable for this.

Comment: Suppose you got the link to a pic- www.mysite.com/123/img/mypic.jpg but you're not supposed to see it, how do I authenticate it? @ronniskansing

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the following methods

**1. [Security through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)** *(Not recommended, but easy!)*

By creating the big enough hash prefix (eg. random 64 characters alphanum) and it's entropy would be an overkill for any current bruteforcing method. If someone is hellbent still, there would be other problems that you should be worrying about.

One caveat though, your images will have this humongous image names(though I have seen this implemented in many sites already).

Then you can maintain the access control through php algorithm, as to who has the link to this image.

**2. Stream the file through `php`.** *(Recommended, extra coding required)*

Generally whenever a non-executable file is accessed through Apache, it just starts outputting the file content with the respective header. But if an executable file (modules for which have been loaded by Apache) is accessed, instead of directly outputting the file, Apache sends the execution request to the respective module and once the module completes the execution of the script, then it sends back the output to Apache which in turn is sent to the client.

Here you can make a `.php` file that handles all the file access, and inside it you can perform all the authentication/authorization checks that you wish to perform and once owner confirmed you can send the file through php as shown below.

```
// After validating the user is logged-in and is the rightful owner of the said file.

// the file you want to send, the user doesnt need to know this, it could we outside of the webroot too, just make sure php has access to it.
$path = "secret/path/to/the/file/to/be/downloaded";

// the file name of the download
$public_name = basename($path);

// get the file's mime type to send the content type header
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $path);

// send the respective headers
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$public_name;");
header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));

// stream the file
$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

Comment: Did you check out Facebook's images? They are like aka.akamai-hd.net/fbstatic/scontent-xx/ something.jpg, the images are cleanly stored in the cdn with jpg formats and the pictures are showed with <img src="actual link">. So how do I do that without compromising user privacy?

Answer (score -2):

You could simply use an sha1 hash name like this:

```
$salt = "MySecretSalt";
$filename = sha1($username.$salt.microtime());
```

You will then have a filename 40 characters long.

Comment: Security through obscurity is terrible practice. OP is probably looking for authentication.

Comment: Exactly, how do I achieve that?

Comment: @PeeHaa It's not as terrible as you might think. Compare the security of an obscure password to the security of an obscure URL. And ask yourself how this password will be shared? Related question [Is including a secret GUID in an URL Security Through Obscurity?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36870/is-including-a-secret-guid-in-an-url-security-through-obscurity)

Comment: A password can be changed easily. Changing all the hashes of the images, not so much.

Comment: So, how do I achieve this?